# Qt: update - add ui objects to existing window at runtime

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to add ui objects (buttons, text boxes etc) to a visible qt window, i.e. I have a window that has a QTextEdit where the user can add a number, then there is a button to add another QTetEdit for another number and a button to remove it. This means that i can add an arbitrary number of fields and later on i can perform some sort of calculation on the all the elements, because I need to be able to add an arbitrary number of extra objects so showing and hiding elements would probably be inefficient. This is a made up example but it demonstrates the purpose of what I'm after.

Has anyone done anything similar?

-- update --

Heres some code I am trying thats not working for me, the window is already visible when the code runs:

```
void MainWindow::addArgument()
{
    QPushButton button;
    ui->addArgRowHorizontalLayout->addWidget(&button);
    button.show();
    this->show();
}
```

anybody know what im doing wrong, everything autocompletes in qtcreator and compiles with no errors so i dont know where to go next.

j

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm refering to contents of update.
Have you moved to C++ from C#/Java?

```
QPushButton button;
```

This instruction creates QPushButton object on **stack**, and objects on stack are destroyed when their scope ends, which in this case is function's closing bracket. To make an object persistant you should allocate it on **heap**:

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton();
```

Of course, you have to use pointer semantics from now on.

Typically in C++ you have to manually **delete** objects from heap when your application's logic don't need them any longer. Thankfully, Qt keeps track of QObject, so you rarely have to dispose them by yourself. A good place to start C++ is [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/). Also, you should go through Qt manual, it's really easy to read and get Qt's concepts.

Comment: thanks, i just figured it out myself but ill be sure to read the faq, and im constantly reading the qt manual, it just takes some time so go in, im still extremely new to this:)

Comment: And also I havent dont java before, some other interpreted languages though, mel (maya embeded language) and a tiny bit of actionscript2.0 a long time ago, but i wish i didn't do that, im getting on much better with c++ already, j

Answer (score 3):

I managed to dynamically add widgets to my main window like this:

MainWindow::addWidget() is a slot of MainWindow

```
void MainWindow::addWidget()
{
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton;
    ui->HorizontalLayout->addWidget(button);
    button->show();
}
```

Simple when you know how:)

Comment: To avoid leaks, your QPushButton should be created as a Children of the window : this way, when the window is released, so is your button(`new QPushButton(this)`). You can check the code generated by the UIC to get ideas :-)

Comment: @Bruce: that is generally the case.  Just to clarify, however, when the button was added to the layout, it automatically set the parent of the button appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. There is nothing that prevents you from dynamically adding or removing widgets from layouts dynamically.

You might want to look into the [`adjustSize()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#adjustSize) functions that you probably will have to call if your container(s) need re-sizing after the layout change.

Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing mysterious about how Qt creates its ui objects: Qt Designer generates C++ source code, which you can look through. If your form name is `MyForm.ui`, then you should find a file `ui_MyForm.h` in the build directory; the function `setupUi` in that file shows you how the ui is built up from scratch.